# error while modifying xml integer value in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

What can I use instead of `settextcontent` for updating integer value? When I use `settextcontent` to update integer value, the cmd throws out this error

```
settextcontent(java.lang.string) in org.w3c.dom.node cannot be applied to (int)
```

Comment: You need to be vareful with Upper and lower case. The string class in Java is `java.lang.String` . Similarly I suspect you should use `org.w3c.dom.Node`. Typos like these will cause many problems!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your method argument to a String, like this: `String.valueOf(val)`